# Curl не отправляет фото

Tags: curl, php

Добрый день, пытаюсь отправить фото через curl. Скрипт  полностью рабочий, на винде файл скриптом отправляется нормально, как только перенёс на сервер (freebsd) то не хочет отправлять, заполняю массив таким образом:

```
$data_image['Filename1']= '@'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/original/'.$user_object_data['image_1']; 
$data_image['Filename2']= '@'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/original/'.$user_object_data['image_2']; 
$data_image['Filename3']= '@'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../images/original/'.$user_object_data['image_3'];
```

вывод var_dump:

Win Srv:

```
string(77) "@C:\AppServ\www\curl/../images/original/PHOTO_491714303_1354955143_realty.jpg"
```

BSD srv:

```
string(93) "@/usr/local/www/curl/../images/original/PHOTO_946861521_1354956032.jpg"
```

Дерриктории все рабочие, если я делаю скажем cd /usr/local/www/curl/../images/original то перехожу в папку с фото. На все директории выставлял для теста права 777 результата нет. Может у кого был подобного роба трабл?

З.Ы. Даже указывал прямые пути, не помогает...

Comment: Рас уж вы указывали и прямые пути то смею предположить что файла PHOTO_946861521_1354956032.jpg просто нет.

Comment: К сожалению он есть :)
Как видно из кода выше он берётся из массива, сам массив берётся из таблицы мускула, в таблицу он добавляется скриптом при аплоде файлов на локальный сервер, имя этого файла генерируется и добавляется к имени файла и в таблицу.

Если бы файла небыло curl выдал бы ошибку (специально для вас проверил изменив название в таблицу, добавив в конец 2):

Error CURL: couldn't open file "/usr/local/www/images/original/PHOTO_946861521_13549560322.jpg" | Error number: 26

Comment: UNIX подобные системы очень любят регистр - а винде на регистр наплевать, может здесь собака зарыта. Самые распространенные ошибки с переходом на Unix - это слеши в путях, регистрозависимость и пермишены.

Comment: Тоже так думал, изменял в таблицах название файла на 1.jpg давал права, в ответ болт.

var_dump:

string(53) "@/usr/local/www/images/original/1.jpg" 

Я все скрипты страюсь писать кросс платформенные, curl отлично отправляет все данные кроме фото... в винде всё ок....

Не стоит забывать что все имена файлов генерируются (об этом я писал выше) и после записи файла добавляются в таблицу, откуда потом и берутся.

Comment: А вы просто всем файлам давали права 777 или той папке которая с файлами?
Просто может быть доступа в папку нет. И тогда не важно какие права у файлов...

Попробуйте как-нибудь chmod -R 777 images

Comment: Давал и файлам и папке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашёл, не было времени отписаться. Всё из за фронта nginx, который не давал сделать, нужно было "принудительно" указать тип файлов (в самом массиве). Причём такая приблуда работает только на связке apache + nginx на голом апаче работать не будет.

Answer (score 0):

CURLE_READ_ERROR (26): There was a problem reading a local file or an error returned by the read callback. не может прочитать файл - весь фокус с пермишинами: записан файл одним пользователем youname, а читается другим nobody/www-user или т.п. , а разрешения на файл стоят очевидно 500  или 555 или что-то подобное. Поставь разрешение 544 или + r

Comment: CURLE_READ_ERROR (26) Вы видимо читали между строк, так как я специально изменил имя файла, добавив лишнюю 2 что бы показать что всё ок.

chmod ставил 777 на исполняемый скрипт и на файл с фото (на всякий случай)